# Unable to Add or Remove applications in Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: installation, software-center, uninstall

I am trying to add or remove applications from Ubuntu Software Center but ending up with the following error

```
Software can't be installed or removed because the authentication service is 
not available. 
(org.freedesktop.PolicyKit.Error.Failed: ('system-bus-name', {'name': ':1.74'}): 
org.debian.apt.install-or-remove-packages
```

[image]

apt-get install  or apt-get remove  works good from command line, but doesn't in USC

Any help ???

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling the software center since apt-get is working fine?

Answer (score 0):

Try rebooting and then

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

There might be another process in the background preventing Ubuntu Software Center from installing what you want.

Comment: tried but, didnt work